# Toggle dropdown by clicking a button jquery

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

I have a drop down by bootstrap design (link: http://prntscr.com/124hf4), When I am clicking on the "Try it" button the drop-down opens but when I click everywhere on the screen it closes. I need it to close only when I click the "Try it" button again. I got rid of ideas and don't know how to do it.

Edit:
I have a hide function where I have tried modified alot thinks but couldn't get anything.
here is the function code:`null;

```
function hide(event) {
    $('span').click(function() {
        // In some cases we don't hide them
        var targetGroup = event ? $(event.target).parents().addBack() : 
        // Are we clicking anywhere in a dropdown?
        if( targetGroup && targetGroup.is('.dropdown') ) {
            // Is it a dropdown menu?
            if( targetGroup.is('.dropdown-menu') ) {
                // Did we click on an option? If so close it.
                if( !targetGroup.is('A') ) return;
            } else {
                // Nope, it's a panel. Leave it open.
                return;
            }
        }

        // Hide any dropdown that may be showing
        $(document).find('.dropdown:visible').each( function() {
            var dropdown = $(this);
            dropdown
                .hide()
                .removeData('dropdown-trigger')
                .trigger('hide', { dropdown: dropdown });
        });

        // Remove all dropdown-open classes
        $(document).find('.dropdown-open').removeClass('dropdown-open');
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

The second line with the click event is a a failture try of what I wanted to do.

Comment: Do you have any code you could post? It will help people solve your problem faster.

Comment: could u use http://jsfiddle.net/ for show us ur html and js

Comment: May I know what jquery version is you are using? And are you using any library?